# Sum total quantity from table1 and add it on table2

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables  tblsales and tblproduct. tblsales have | id | pcode | qty|  and tblproduct have   | id | pcode | pleft | . my question is that I want to total all qty value from tblsales and add it to pleft in tblproduct. I tried what I have learn in MYSQL programming but it doesn't work for me.

for example

tblsales

```
| id | pcode | qty | 
| 1  |  455  |  1  |
| 2  |  455  |  1  |
```

tblproduct

```
| id | pcode | pleft | 
| 4  |  455  |  5    | <--- this is the current value with out update
```

here is my problem. so if I would click the  button, the tblproduct must be update. something like this result

tblproduct

```
| id | pcode | pleft |
| 4  |  455  |  7    | <--- this must be the value after clicking the button.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the stuff:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM tblsales)+(SELECT SUM(pleft) FROM tblproduct) AS total_sum
```

in case that you're trying to get all table data.
But if you're going to group it by `pcode`, that is different task:

```
SELECT pcode, SUM(pcode_sum) AS total_sum
FROM
  (SELECT pcode, SUM(qty) AS pcode_sum AS FROM tblsales GROUP BY pcode
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pcode, SUM(pleft) AS pcode_sum FROM tblproduct GROUP BY pcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your table:

```
UPDATE tblproduct 
    SET pleft=pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty) 
                      FROM tblsales 
                     WHERE tblsales.pcode=tblproduct.pcode)
```

If you need just select then:

```
SELECT Id,PCode,pleft+(SELECT SUM(qty) 
                          FROM tblsales 
                         WHERE tblsales.pcode=tblproduct.pcode)
FROM tblproduct
```